# Natural deduction proof of a simple formula.

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I am trying to prove the following formula using only natural deduction system:
$$\vdash (A \supset (A \supset B)) \supset (A \supset B),$$
and this, according to natural deduction rules leads to
$$A \supset (A \supset B) \vdash A \supset B,$$
and then
$$A \supset (A \supset B),A \vdash B.$$

It seems obvious, but I cannot find the matching rule to get the identity. Would you give me some hints please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to prove a conditional. So assume the antecedent and aim for the consequent, which is $(A \to B)$.

The consequent is another conditional. So again, you assume the antecedent $A$ as another temporary assumption and aim for the new consequent $C$.

Setting out the resulting obvious proof Fitch-style we get ...

$\quad\quad|\quad (A \to (A \to B))\\
\quad\quad|\quad\quad|\quad A\\
\quad\quad|\quad\quad|\quad (A \to B)\\
\quad\quad|\quad\quad|\quad B\\
\quad\quad|\quad (A \to B)\\
((A \to (A \to B)) \to (A \to B))
$

Annotating the steps here can be left as an exercise.

Comment: Could you explain this, please?

Comment: So, do you mean that we must prove the formula $\vdash A \supset (A \supset B))$? If so, I still don't get it: this leads to $A \vdash A \supset B$, and then $A,A \vdash B$. How do we «connect» this to our previous proof?

Comment: No, $A \to (A \to B)$ is a temporary assumption for the sake of argument. It is of the essence of a Natural Deduction system that we can make and then discharge temporary assumption. Consult any good text on ND.

Comment: Okay, could you then please explain your notation, because I do not know, how to follow it.

Comment: Try, e.g. http://tellerprimer.ucdavis.edu/pdf/1ch5.pdf

Comment: @mikroz In the first line, we suppose that $A\rightarrow (A\rightarrow B)$. In the 2nd line line, we suppose $A$. What can we infer from these 2 assumptions?

Comment: Where can I read some decent explanation of Fitch style proofs if I already know natural deduction proofs?